# Path-based routing question for NGINX ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, k3s

Is it possible route traffic to backend services via custom URIs, like:

`https://myhost.com/wiki` in my browser would route traffic to my wiki service

`https://myhost.com/plex` in my browser would route traffic to my plex service

This (current) ingress configuration works to route traffic to the Plex service, but not the wiki service:

```
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: mediawiki-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /wiki
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: plex-svc
            port:
              number: 32400
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

EDIT: Upon further investigation, it seems that the two services aren't being routed in the same way.  When accessing Plex by using `https://myhost.com/`, the browser redirects correctly, to `https://myhost.com/web/index.html/blah/blah`.  But when I try to access `https://myhost.com/wiki`, the URL in the browser gets rewritten and redirected to `http://myhost/index.php/Main_Page`, and a 404 not found.

Comment: Yes. If you're asking "but how?" this is not a consultancy website -- what have you already tried and what outcome is it producing for you? Don't put that information in the comments, instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75575482/edit) and provide the code and your tests

Answer (score 0):

You can use Path based routing as per this [simple fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout). In this configuration you can route traffic from a single IP address or host to multiple services located in the backend pool by using the Path and also to  use path-based routing, you need to create separate listener rules for each URL path. The listener rules specify the backend server pool to which the traffic should be routed. For example, if you wanted to route traffic for /wiki to one backend pool, and traffic for /plex to another backend pool, you would need to create two separate listener rules. Each listener rule would then have the appropriate URL path specified in the rule. You can see below yaml referred from official documentation.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /wiki
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 4200
      - path: /plex
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: Yes, I thought so too.  But, when I use the simple fanout configuration, I get 404 errors, like it's not routing traffic to the backends correctly.  If I set `path: /` then it works as expected, but I obviously can't route to multiple services with this configuration.

Comment: @GreNIX : if you are getting a  404 error configuration, it seems that the service is not accepting the request which means you need to have a recheck configuration of service and application. Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? if not let me know the error you are facing so that will address the issue.